# Why is this semaphore code failing?

Tags: c, linux, unix, semaphore

```
#include <semaphore.h>


sem_t mutex;


int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{



sem_init (&mutex,0,1); 

}
```

I'm getting:

```
/tmp/ccAMFxDX.o: In function `main':
programaservidor.c:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `sem_init'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the sem_init() man page

> Link with -lrt or -pthread.

As in `gcc your_code.c -lpthread -o your_code`

Comment: I'm pretty new at this. Can you describe in a little more detail what you mean by linking with -lrt or -pthread?

Comment: @Unome sure, see [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) to get a better understand of what linking is.  Anytime you see an `-l<something>` option passed to a gcc command, that is a directive telling the linker that it needs to look at a library called <something> to find the necessary object code to create the executable.  In the OP's case, the object code for the function called `sem_init` is located in the `pthread` library.

Comment: Awesome that makes sense, the code I was given was wrapped up with a make file, so i had to add the -pthread into that for it to run. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the man page, you have to link with either `-lrt` or `-pthread`.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant POSIX reference is:

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html#tag_20_11_13